# Koala SCSS - Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory

Tags: css, sass, koala

Here is a structure of my project:

> 1. css dir
>
>    - style.css (there should be compiled and minified style.scss)
> 2. font dir
> 3. js dir
> 4. sass dir
>
>    - components dir (files from materializecss)
>    - _main.css (my custom styles)
>    - _materialize.scss (import components from materializecss)
>    - style.scss (import materialize.scss and main.scss)
> 5. index.html

When I try compile style.scss in Koala, I get error message:

```
C:\Users\Paweł\Desktop\tw2\sass\style.scss
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - C:\Users\Pawe�\Desktop\tw2\sass\style.scss
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

I'm Windows 7 32bit user, I don't have installed Ruby or something other stuff. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hi. Were you able to figure this out? I'm having the same problem and this question hasn't been updated in 10 months.

Comment: Hey, I don't know if it was a solution but you can try put your project into C:/ drive and then check.

Answer (score 0):

Set Koala to use the system SASS compiler, maybe will fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it`s usual problem with non latin symbols. I had same problems and the solution was to change the directory which shown as '?' on latin symbol and all compiled.